# using $.post() and return to object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

```
<button>Test 1</button>
<button>Test 2</button>
<button>Test 3</button>
```

so something like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
     $.post('a.php',{text:$(this).text()},function(data){
          if(data == 'doThis'){
            $(this)...(??button??)...css('color','#ff0000');
          }else{
            $(this)...(??button??)...css('color','#00ffff');
          }
     });
});
```

So, depending on "a.php" result.. the button will have something different.
I have no idea the number os buttons, and the idea is one function to all..
How you people would do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (untested)

```
$('button').click(function(){
 var btn = $(this);
 $.post('a.php',{text:$(this).text()},function(data){
      if(data == 'doThis'){
        btn.css('color','#ff0000');
      }else{
         btn.css('color','#00ffff');
      }
     });
});
```

Storing an instance of the button as `btn` allows you to call it within the anon function of $.post, keeping the reference even if the click event is executed several times before .post can return a valid.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary reference to `this` to maintain closure:

```
$('button').click(function(){
     var self = this;
     $.post('a.php',{text:$(self).text()},function(data){
         $(self).css('color',(data == 'doThis') ? '#ff0000' : '#00ffff');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, another option would be to use `$.ajax`, and set the `context` option to `this`, making the clicked button the context for the success callback:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "a.php", 
    type: "post",
    data: {text:$(this).text()},
    context: this, 
    success: function(data) {
      if(data == 'doThis'){
        $(this).css('color','#ff0000');
      }else{
         $(this).css('color','#00ffff');
      }      
    }
});
```